# My cat hasn't pooped in 2 days, what should I do?

Tags: cats, health, defecation

My cat hasn't pooped in 2 days. How long do cats typically go between pooping? How long should I wait before I take him to the vet?

He is a neutered male domestic short hair, about three years old and otherwise in good health.

Comment: (Not a problem I'm having, but spoke to a friend about her cat this weekend)

Comment: Going to sound gross, but can you see the poop?

Comment: @JohnCavan I didn't think to ask at the time, but I think she would have said so if she did.

Comment: Hmm... would be good to know. I have a similar issue with my cat, so I can supply what we've done with our Vet's instructions.

Comment: I too have had a cat who deveoped mega colon. I think its important this cat visit the vet fairly urgently so that the cause of the constipation can be identified and treated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, for the short answer on this, I would get him into the vet to check his hydration and to, possibly, clean him out. Not so much because he's in immediate danger, but because there are long term risks with this situation in the formation of [megacolon](http://www.peteducation.com/article.cfm?c=1%202122&aid=3471). As you know, cats are not necessarily avid drinkers and this becomes more risky if a cat is prone to constipation and he may well be. The food he eats and the amount of water he drinks will play a real role here.

There may be nothing to it, but if he's not getting the moisture in his diet, then a change in diet may help. In addition to wet cat food, I would recommend adding water to it to increase the moisture content. We do that with our cat that suffers from megacolon and it makes a big difference, in conjunction with some medications, in keeping him regular. The goal is to make the stool soft enough so that a cat with weak muscles can still move the stool through the system.

Comment: Instead of water, we had been advised to add either liquid parafin or olive oil (10mls max) to our cat's food.

Answer (score 3):

Does your cat vomit, or has it tried vomiting recently? If he/she does, it might be a result of excessive hairballs, as constipation for cats might also be caused by excessive hairballs. In my case, I have tried giving my cat some Hairball & Laxatives and Hairball remedies, and it works well. For a safer and cheap remedy, try giving your cat some cat grass or wheat grass to clear the hairballs.

As what the previous answer suggests, it is good to constantly supply your cat with clean water and not too many dry treats if he/she is getting older. Veterinarians suggest that it's more efficient for cats to absorb water from wet food rather than just water.